# Zend 2 Form Issue

Tags: php, zend-framework2, phpstorm

I have updated framework to 2.3.1. Now form classes showing following error in PhpStrom.

```
Class must be declared abstract or implement method 'setOption'
```

[image]

What should i do ?

Comment: What class are you extending? `Zend\Form\Form`?

Answer (score 0):

You are extending your class not from \Zend\Form\Form
There is no errors with default Zend Form class.

Try to check what instance of Form you extends. Check your use statements and also check modules for \Zend\Form\Form overloads.